# Windows Update PowerShell Module Display Category With Get-WindowsUpdate

Tags: powershell

My problem is I don't know how to view the title only of each available update using the Get-WindowsUpdate.
When I run `Get-WindowsUpdate` I get this:[image]

I would like to only display the names.
[image]

I do not know mush about powershell but I tried the below but I it did not work:

```
Get-WindowsUpdate | Select-Object Title| Format-Table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ken,

Try it this way.

```
PS> (Get-WindowsUpdate).Title | ft
```

Output:

```
Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Versi
on 1.379.955.0)
Dell. - Firmware - 0.1.0.23
Intel - SoftwareComponent - 1.41.2021.121
Intel - SoftwareComponent - 1.63.1155.1
Intel - SoftwareComponent - 2130.1.16.1
SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd.  - Modem - 2.19.1.0
```